# Website functioning inside android web view

Tags: android, webview, android-webview

I am new to android and am eagerly seeking help for finding out how to integrate my website inside android web view.I have been through some android tutorials for webview.Got a bit of good grip but still have some doubts.
I have my website say xyz.com.It as an online shopping website.Now i have made it responsive enough to appear like an app in mobile devices(its still a website).Now instead of coding in from scratch to develop an app for the same.Can i achieve the website functionality inside android web view.Say i click 'buy now' for a particular product,it redirects me to the checkout process in my website,i.e,loads another web page.It has javascript and css running along with it.
Would be glad to go ahead with anyone's help.
Please suggest me with a suitable explanation and example.

Comment: Hi ammar,i am actually researching through this so as to start with its implementation once i am confirmed that it will work fine.So,okay,as you said if i enable javascript in my web view.Then will my existing website work in the same manner in adroid webview as it works on a browser.Will i have to incorporate java code to handle the javasrcipt of my web page.

Answer (score 0):

did you try to enable the javascript in your web view using this code ??

```
WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();
webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
```

and what the problem that you have now in your site ??

Comment: Hi ammar,i am actually researching through this so as to start with its implementation once i am confirmed that it will work fine.So,okay,as you said if i enable javascript in my web view.Then will my existing website work in the same manner in adroid webview as it works on a browser.Will i have to incorporate java code to handle the javasrcipt of my web page.

Answer (score 0):

// I used this class and my code is working fime at my side please try this may be it will help you

```
public class WebViewActivity extends Activity {
    private WebView webview;
    private static final String TAG = "Main";
    private ProgressDialog progressBar;
    private TextView header_maintext;
    private TextView headeroptiontext;
    private RelativeLayout back;
    private String url_string="http://www.google.com";
    private String header_maintext_string="Your text";  

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled") @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
         setContentView(R.layout.webview_layout);


        webview = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webview01);
        header_maintext= (TextView)findViewById(R.id.header_maintext);
        header_maintext.setText(header_maintext_string);

        headeroptiontext = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.headeroptiontext);
        headeroptiontext.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        WebSettings settings = webview.getSettings();
        settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webview.setScrollBarStyle(WebView.SCROLLBARS_OUTSIDE_OVERLAY);
        webview.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
        webview.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);

          back = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.back_layout);
          back.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) 
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if(webview.canGoBack() == true)
                    {
                        webview.goBack();
                    }
                else
                    {
                        finish();
                    }
             }
        });

        final AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).create();

        progressBar = ProgressDialog.show(WebViewActivity.this, "My application", "Loading...");

        webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {

                view.loadUrl(url);
                return true;
            }

            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                Log.i(TAG, "Finished loading URL: " +url);
                if (progressBar.isShowing()) {
                    progressBar.dismiss();
                }
            }

            public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {

                Toast.makeText(WebViewActivity.this, "Oh no! " + description, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                alertDialog.setTitle("Error");
                alertDialog.setMessage(description);
                alertDialog.setButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        return;
                    }
                });
                alertDialog.show();
            }
        });
        webview.loadUrl(url_string);


    }
    @Override

    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if(event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
            switch(keyCode)
            {
            case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK:
                if(webview.canGoBack() == true){
                    webview.goBack();
                }else{
                    finish();
                }
                return true;
            }

        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }
}
```

this is a xml for web view

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
     <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="46dp"
        android:background="#002E3E" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/back_layout"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/back"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:src="@drawable/back_arow" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/logoimage"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/back"
                android:src="@drawable/top_logo" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/header_maintext"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/logoimage"
                android:text="@string/signup"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:textSize="16sp" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/headeroptiontext"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:text="@string/signup"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="16sp" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/headeroptionimage"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:src="@drawable/option"
            android:visibility="gone" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="2dp"
        android:background="#33B5E5" >
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>

        <WebView
            android:id="@+id/webview01"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1" >
        </WebView>

    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Hi Bhanu,i am actually researching through this so as to start with its implementation once i am confirmed that it will work fine.So,okay,as you said if i enable javascript in my web view.Then will my existing website work in the same manner in adroid webview as it works on a browser.Will i have to incorporate java code to handle the javasrcipt of my web page.The above method that u prescribed ,did it render your website to work in a webview as it would work in a normal browser.

Comment: have u try to get some data from web website via java script coz in this ans u can only display the website and it will work as same as on web browser